# Fatal error while running task to run and compile the c program

Tags: c, json, powershell, visual-studio

I was trying to compile and run code using "run task" instead of code runner extension.
Run task was successful when I just tried to compile the program and run it manually but when I tried to compile and run in same task following error occurred:

```
cc1.exe: fatal error: world\hello_world.c: No such file or directory
```

tasks.json code :

```
{
 "version": "2.0.0",
 "tasks": [
     {
         "type": "cppbuild",
         "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
         "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
         "args": [
             "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
             "-g",
             "${file}",
             "-o",
             "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
         ],
         "options": {
             "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
         },
         "problemMatcher": [
             "$gcc"
         ],
         "group": {
             "kind": "build",
             "isDefault": true
         },
         "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
     },
     {
         "type": "shell",
         "label": "Run C Program",
         "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g ${file} ${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe s-and${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
         
         "options": {
             "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
         },
         "problemMatcher": [
             "$gcc"
         ],
     
         "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
     }
 ]
}
```

Comment: The error does not contain the full path "world\hello_world.c".  Code is looking for the file in the file in a relative folder.  I had similar issue a couple of years ago on a Raspberry.  Code compiled correctly on Window but not on a Linux machine.  Solution was to use CD to change the folder before compiling.  On windows the compiler was able to compile a file in a subfolder but on Linux you had to change to folder before compiling.

Comment: I am able to compile by "run task", but not able to run and compile both by executing single task. And it's working by changing cd but that's manual way right,? Can you suggest any changes that i should do in tasks.json file for it?

Comment: You can put into a bat file (or powershell script) and add the CD bat/ps1 file.

Comment: Thank you for your help sir/ma'am, i tried redoing all stuff and setting up again as mentioned in vs code official page and it worked.Again  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Edit : add include path, if your launch/or task .json file being created automatically but without any much properties/code in it then try creating again by following proper instructions on vsc page. For launch.json : click on "settings" icon right side of "run code" (play icon) button.